# How to get spine current animation

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I have a simple spine project in cocos2d and I want to know the current animation that's being played (the string name) but I can't find any function to get that in the CCSkeletonAnimation class,

Do you know if there's a way to get that?

Thanks

**EDIT - SOLUTION**

Hey I found how to to it

```
AnimationState *a = [mAnimationNode getAnimationState:0];   
NSLog(@"Layer touched: %s",a->animation->name);
```

Where mAnimationNode is a CCSkeletonAnimation,

that works perfectly!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey I found how to to it

```
AnimationState *a = [mAnimationNode getAnimationState:0];   
NSLog(@"Layer touched: %s",a->animation->name);
```

Where mAnimationNode is a CCSkeletonAnimation,

that works perfectly!!

Comment: for cocos2d-x: anim->getCurrent()->animation->name

Answer (score 0):

If Spine does not support a clear way to do it, you might be better off by storing the animation name in a property of your scene when you start it.

On the other hand, since an animation is usually implemented in cocos2d through an action, you could inspect the `CCActionManager`'s `numberOfRunningActionsInTarget:` method implementation to check how you can access the list of running actions in a given target node.

This is for cocos2d 1.1:

```
tHashElement *element = NULL;
HASH_FIND_INT(targets, &target, element);
```

`element->actions` is the ccArray containing all the running actions.